Knights and Knaves with Layers
In front of you is a knight (always telling the truth) and a knave (always lying). We call these two gentlemen "pair $A$", and you don't know which is which.
Behind them are three pairs, $B$, $C$ and $D$. You know that these pairs' compositions of knights and knaves looks like this: (knight, knight), (knight, knave) and (knave, knave), but you do not know which is which.
Behind the three pairs are two doors: door 1 and 2. One leads to freedom, and one to death, but you don't know which. Your goal is to guarantee your escape by asking yes-or-no questions to the knights and knaves, to which they will answer either yes or no. However, there are some rules:

You can only direct a question to a single knight/knave at a time.
You cannot ask a member of pair $A$ any questions regarding the doors.
Once you ask a question of a member of pair $B$, $C$ or $D$, you cannot pose a question to a member of any other pair.
Paradoxical questions, or questions about the future, will not be answered by anyone; knight or knave.

Give a solution using the smallest maximum number of questions, and prove that it is indeed such a solution.
The next room...

Attribution: Me

@AlexRavsky Oh yeah I forgot to add the yes/no restriction. And as far as I know I am the first to make this puzzle.

This question is similar to: Two doors with two guards - one lies, one tells the truth. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@noedne The solution is the same, but this puzzle is a part of a series. In this series, each puzzle has the same structure, but is an evolved version of the previous. This is a degenerate case of that structure where a certain element is actually pointless (but that element isn't in later entries to the series). So, in this entry to the series, the "pointless" element serves only a role of distraction and also to set up a recurring structure.

Maybe instead of linking to this duplicate question, the question using jokers could include a note that removing the jokers reduces the question to the original classical problem?


 It suffices to ask one question.


 Indeed, pick any gentleman $G$ from any of the pairs $B$, $C$, and $D$.


 Let $X$ be the statement "$G$ is a knight" and $Y$ be the statement "Door $1$ leads to freedom".


 Ask $G$ whether $X$ is logically equivalent to $Y$, that is "$X\equiv Y$?"


 It is easy to check that the answer should be "Yes" iff Door $1$ leads to freedom.


Great... but the term "freedom" was perhaps a bit of a exaggeration.... muhahaha (see my next question)

@user110391 I am from Soviet Union, where we were taught that freedom is perceived necessity. :-)

You can deduce the door that leads to freedom by asking

 just one question.

Solution:

 Point to one of the doors and then ask one person from Pair B (or C or D) the following question:

 “If I were to ask you if this is the door that leads to freedom what would you say?”

 If the person was a knight then they would answer correctly to the simple question, “Is this the door that leads to freedom?” They would truthfully report how they would answer this simple question.

 If the person was a knave then they would answer incorrectly to the simple question, “Is this the door that leads to freedom?“ But then they would incorrectly report how they would answer this simple question.

 The double negation from the knave gives the correct information just like the knight does.

 In either case, if they say Yes, then it is the door that leads to freedom.  Otherwise it leads to death.


Since Alex gave a solution before you, his answer would be accepted regardless, so the following does not really matter, but can be an interesting discussion in its own right: it can be argued that your question is not a yes-or-no question, thus violating the puzzle. You see, a yes-or-no question is one where the answer must be either [yes] or [no]. To your question, the answer can, outside of context, be any string. In context, we know that string must be ["yes"] or ["no"], given that the gentlemen only utter these words. [1/2]

[2/2]  But, the answer is nonetheless ["yes"] or ["no"], as opposed to [yes] or [no]. Given that  the answer is mention of a string, instead of an affirmative/negative, it means that your question is not a yes-or-no question. To say that it is a yes-or-no question would be tantamount to conflating the use of a word with the mention of a word. However, that's just my opinion, which does not matter all that much given that Alex's answer is already accepted. However, I merely thought I'd raise the question regarding the validity of your answer out of academic interest. Thoughts anyone?

@user110391 Actually, the problem is a bit worse—a knave could easily answer something other than yes/no, e.g., "box". You'd know they're a knave, but not whether Door 1 is safe or not. A simple modification would be replacing "what would you say?" with "would you say yes?" This is what I consider the classical answer to the knight-and-knave problem.
